# Making Attendance App in Android

Tags: java, android, json, http

I have to make attendance app for college.The app will take data from colleges website and display it on app according to user login and password.

When we login into college's website we have to put `id` and `password`, same thing I want on my app so that user can see it on an app itself.

I have searched `httpurlconnection`, `httpget`, `httppost`, `jsoup`.

Up till now, I have understood that I have to make `httprequest` for loading the college's attendance site and then `httppost` to post username and password and after that `jsoup` to grab the data from HTML page.

But I have seen tutorials only to request JSON pages, but how to request for HTML pages?and post login to it?

Here is what I tried and collected data from JSON

```
private  TextView textresponse1;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Button Get= (Button) findViewById(R.id.httprequest);
      textresponse1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textresponse);
      progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
      Get.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {    

      new JSONTask().execute("https://jsonparsingdemo-cec5b.firebaseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoList.txt");
      progressDialog.setMessage("Collecting Data");
      progressDialog.show();
 }

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String >{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
              URL url=new URL(params[0]);
              connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              connection.connect();

              InputStream stream=connection.getInputStream();

              reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

              String line="";
              StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
              while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

              String finaljosn=buffer.toString();
              StringBuffer add =new StringBuffer();
              JSONObject parentobject=new JSONObject(finaljosn);
              JSONArray parentarray=parentobject.getJSONArray("movies");
              for(int i=0;i<parentarray.length();i++) {
                   JSONObject moviename = parentarray.getJSONObject(i);

                   String finalmovie = moviename.getString("movie");
                   int finalyear = moviename.getInt("year");
                   add.append(finalmovie +"- "+finalyear + "\n");
               }
                 return add.toString();
              // return finalmovie +" -Rushabh- " +finalyear;

         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         } finally {
              if (connection!=null) {
                  connection.disconnect();
              }
              try {
                    if (reader!=null) {
                        reader.close();
                   }
              } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }
           }
          return null;
       }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          super.onPostExecute(result);
          progressDialog.dismiss();
          textresponse1.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 String mLoadURL="http://www.google.com";
 
 public class LoadHtml extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(mLoadURL);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                // Get the response
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
             if (!s.trim().isEmpty()) {
               //load html to webview
             }
        }
    }
```

Call Above AsyncTask using:

```
LoadHtml loadHtml= new LoadHtml();
load.execute();
```

Comment: load.execute or loadHtml.execute?

Comment: and i anlso want to post username and password to it

Comment: Sorry its loadHtml.execute(); When website will load , the form will also be loaded and the user will enter their user name and password there by themself.

Comment: how to load html page on app thats what i want to know and then post username and id to it

Comment: you want to post username and password automatically? load above response in webview.

Comment: I want to make my own edit-text in android that can parse username and password to show respective attendance

Comment: i dont want to show webpage of the college,instead i want to show UI of my app

Comment: if you are trying to use you own native form then you must write API for it.

Comment: And for attendance detail you want to load college website page?

Comment: I want to collect username and pasword from app and then post it to webpage

Comment: for attendance details also i will arrange in gson and show it to user,i dont want to show colleges webpage atall

Comment: can you provide college webpage here?

Comment: How to post username and password via app

Comment: You need to write webservice for this in your server